# TextView: how to dynamically change the color of certain word in paragraph

Tags: android, colors, textview

How to change the color of a paragraph word by word with timer. like at first second i want to change color of ***The*** in the below paragraph, after 5th second change color of ***text***, after 8th second change color of ***will be*** and so on....

```
The text will be wrapped in tags, and displayed in a monospaced font.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and change the font color of your edit text accordingly and stop timer in focus lost.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this :

Split the paragraph to words by using the method :

```
split(String separator);// it will return an array of Strings 
//in your case you will do somthing like this 
myWords = paragraph.split(" ");// the separator is the space
```

And then , you can use the method to colorate what ever you want of those words by using the method :

```
myNewParagraph.append(HTML.fromHtml("<font color...>... Your HTML Code to colorate your Text"));
```

and when you finish coloring each word , you update your textView to display the new text colored

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use spans to control the appearance of text.  Take a look at [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) and [CharacterStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html).

Here is an example.  Of course you would need to put this in some sort of timer.

```
Spannable spannableText = getSpannableText(yourTextView);
spannableText.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(...), wordStart, wordEnd)
yourTextView.setText(spannableText);

private Spannable getSpannableText(TextView tv) {
  CharSequence cs = tv.getText();
  if (cs instanceof Spannable) {
    return (Spannable)cs;
  } else {
    return SpannableString.valueOf(cs);
  }
}
```